# yield from и проблема с возвратом массива значений

Tags: php

Данная написанная мною программа должна осуществлять генерацию и вывод всех возможным комбинаций из трёх цифр, которые могут принимать значения от 1 до 6, проще говоря программа генерирует все возможные варианты броска трёх игральных костей.  Проблема заключается в  возврате и выводе массива каждой комбинации. Я ожидал, что возврат массива значений `$values` будет происходит на команде `yield values` однако программа не возвращала массив комбинаций и заканчивалась по причине нехватки места `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted`. Но при добавлении следующей команды   `return values` , уже начал происходить возврат комбинаций. Почему без `return values` моя программа не работает. До этого я думал, прочитав документацию, что `return` в генераторах нам необходим только в случае , если нам нужен возврат значений с помощью функции `getReturn()`.

```
function generateCombinations($n, $values)
{
    if (count($values) == $n) {
        yield $values;
        return $values; // Почему-то не работает без return
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        yield from generateCombinations($n, array_merge($values, [$i]));
    }

}

$generator = generateCombinations(3, []);
foreach ($generator as $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Протестировав программу без команды `return $values` выяснилось, что программа, после срабатывания условного оператора и возврата комбинации `[1,1,1]`, продолжала свое выполнение, так как функция `yield` возвращает текущее значение, и при следующем вызове функции она возобновит выполнения с места, на котором прервалась. Далее происходил вызов функции `generateCombinations(3, [1,1,1,1])` и потом опять и опять с массивом на 1 элемент больше, то есть она зацикливалась и заканчивала свою работу из-за нехватки памяти. Когда, я добавлял команду `return $values` происходило прекращение работы функции и возврат массива `$values` и дальше происходила итерация по генератору.
Также можно было обойстись без команды `return`. Сделав каким-нибудь образом конец функции, например так:

```
<?php

function generateCombinations($n, $values)
{
    if (count($values) == $n) {
        yield $values;
    } else {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
            yield from generateCombinations($n, array_merge($values, [$i]));
        }
    }
}

$generator = generateCombinations(3, []);
foreach ($generator as $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
?>
```

Добавив команду `else`, то есть изменив условный оператор так, что бы цикл с добавление единицы в массив не срабатывал при выполнения условия  `if (count($values) == $n)`. Тогда функция будет возвращать массив по команде `yield $values` , и в цикл она дальше не попадет и функция закончиться.